# Complicated Database Manipulation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms

I draw a very simple database design for my ASP.NET application and with a little help here and there I managed to implement my design...but I want to insert data to this tables and retrieve from them.

[image]

A very important function in my application will need all the information from all the 7 tables for a certain record, and sometimes I'll need to make my application accept all kinds of related data and place each piece of data in the right table

My questions are :

1. is it normal to have such big design ? is it even big for a real application ?
2. if I want to add a new kid, I'll need to fill all the table with related required information in all the tables, I'll have a big form with some inputs to accept the data, but how will I insert them in to my Database ?
3. If I want to select all the kids, what's the select statement based on this design going to be ?

PS: between every two tables having (M:M) relationship, consider a third table (that will have two primary keys of each of the 2 tables in the relation).

I'm familiar with JOINs and everything, but never applied on such a big design...HELP!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For selecting all the kids, do you want all the included information with them as well, or just the kids themselves? i.e. do you want to know their favorite toys, skills, parents, etc.?

Comment: @guildsbounty - SADLY! I need all information (Fav Toy, Skills, Parents, Sponsers, the sponsership type, fields of work) I know it doesn't make a great sense specially (the fields of work) but the client needs it!

Comment: Sorry to frighten you, but that's a very small database design.

Comment: How familiar are you with interacting with Sql from C#, or Linq to Sql?

Comment: @John Saunders- lol :D actually it's a relief, I thought my design or idea was bad...so it's not that bad -That's Good News- thank you

Comment: @guildsbounty- I use Sql from C# (ADO.NET: basically I create some sql statements inside the ado.net objects then execute them or read them)...but the problem here is the complication!

Comment: Alright, for this case, I'd honestly suggest looking up Linq to SQL. It lets you treat Database tables just like a normal C# object. Additionally, I'm not quite good enough with plain SQL to produce a query to recover all of that data, neatly organized by kid, sponsor, parent, etc... The other convenient part about Linq is that once you have a kid selected, you can very easily 'ride' the relationships between tables to get to all the data directly linked to that specific kid. If you want to stick with ADO, I'm afraid I have to defer to someone with more skill than I.

Comment: @guildsbounty- well, although I would like to know the answer for this question using normal SQL and ADO.NET but if you think LinqToSql is better for this situations, I might read a little about it...do you have any pointers ? articles, books, anything ?

Comment: Just as something to note this doesn't break down what columns would be in each table,e.g. does kid just have a name or is there more like a date of birth, gender, height, weight, etc.

Comment: You don't need a full text book for what you're doing. Linq can do so much more than what I outlined, and most of it is things that you don't really need for your application. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx is a good article by ScottGu, it also includes a demo-video, which I usually find easier to work with than just a text outline.

Comment: @JB King- yeah, it actually don't..I assume who can help me will just say col1 and col2 and I'll modify the code, I think it's not that important for people to bare their minds with such details.

Comment: @guildsbounty- +1 for the link it's nice...but if every table in my design in an object now, can you provide the select code from all the tables (objects) for KidId = 2 for instance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry to frighten you, but that's a very small database design.

When I first started to need to do database designs for web applications, I found a crutch. Fortunately, the crutch I used back then is now available in a free tool, [NORMA](http://www.ormfoundation.org/files/folders/norma_the_software/default.aspx), which works with either Visual Studio 2008 or 2005 (2010 support is coming).

I made a quick guess about your design and got the following ORM model:

[image: Kids and Sponsors]

This led to a database with ten tables, including the junction tables necessary for many to many relationships.

The NORMA tool can generate DDL from the model for several different databases, and can also create XML Schemas and LINQ to SQL objects.

---

BTW, here's an ER diagram of the generated database:

[image: ER]

---

I don't see why you would need all of this in a single resultset, but here's a query which I think might return it all. I haven't tested this with data:

```
SELECT k.KidId, k.Name, k.FavoriteToy, 
    s.SponsorId, s.Name, 
    st.SponsorShipTypeCode, st.Description AS SponsortshipTypeDescription,
    fw.FieldOfWorkCode, fw.Description AS FieldOfWorkDescription,
    Skill.SkillCode, Skill.Description AS SkillDescription,
    Parent.ParentId, Parent.Name AS ParentName
FROM Kid k
LEFT OUTER JOIN KidHasParent ON KidHasParent.KidId = k.KidId
INNER JOIN Parent ON Parent.ParentId = KidHasParent.ParentId
LEFT OUTER JOIN KidHasSkill ON KidHasSkill.KidId = k.KidId
INNER JOIN Skill ON Skill.SkillCode = KidHasSkill.SkillCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sponsor s ON s.SponsorId = k.SponsorId
INNER JOIN SponsorIsOfSponsorShipType Sst ON Sst.SponsorId = s.SponsorId
INNER JOIN SponsorShipType st ON st.SponsorShipTypeCode = sst.SponsorShipTypeCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN SponsorParticipatesInFieldOfWork sfw ON sfw.SponsorId = s.SponsorId
INNER JOIN FieldOfWork fw ON fw.FieldOfWorkCode = sfw.FieldOfWorkCode
```

I created this query by looking at the ORM diagram to know which paths are optional (LEFT JOIN), and then by using a tool (ApexSQL Edit) which uses the foreign keys to help me build joins. This took under ten minutes.

Comment: John thanks, It's my first time to hear about this tool
but it won't help me with selecting my information ? and how good is it ? I mean can I depend on it in a real applications and my job ? or writing ADO.NET and LinqToSql is better ?

Comment: You can absolutely depend on it in terms of creating database models and producing DDL from that. The tool has been out for some time, and is maintained by the same people who created the original "crutch" I used back in 2002. It was the "Object-Role Modeling" feature of Visio for Enterprise Architects, but that's now available as this free tool. The "free" part simply means that enhancements don't come as quickly as if you were paying for them, for instance, VS2010 support should be out within a month.

Comment: sorry John, I still don't see how to get my select query to select all those data at once..I already have done the design part, Thanks for your effort and I'll take a look as soon as the support for VS2010 comes out..but if you can help with an example SELECT statement that would help a lot!

Comment: Finally :D Thanks John..it's really required to have like this big detailed profile page for every kid..so when I search or list the kids I would just retrieve a name and a sponsor or maybe just a name...but this detailed page is required to have every little detail...btw I like the tools you use for helping you out!

Comment: Marked as answer...a different yet related question, do you think using NHibarnate and this stuff would be better than just plan SQL ?

Comment: It depends on what you're familiar with and such. If you have people who are comfortable writing stored procedures, then go with it. You may find Entity Framework or NHibernate to be a better development option for you.

Comment: @John Saunders- I've studied your query and I've been trying to use ever since...but I discovered that it duplicates the kidId one time and doesn't the other one if the result should be : 1 2 2 3 4...the query outputs : 1 2 2 2 2 3 4 4! I think it's because you use the kidId two times in binding but still it's essential for the bound! any solutions for this bug ?

Comment: It's going to duplicate a lot of things, since you insist on a single flat rowset. I believe you're mistaken to think you need all the columns all at once. You just need to be able to _get_ all the columns, when you need them. For instance, you only need parent information once per parent per kid.

Comment: @John Saunders- Sorry sometimes I don't get notifications for the new comments and I just saw yours.

You're right, I'm not sure If I'm doing exactly what you wanted to say here but I'm now retrieving for example if the kid with all it's associated information, I read the kid table only and then use the kid id and loop to select all it's attributes from the (m:n relation tables). Thanks for ur concern =) +1

Answer (score 3):

1. That is not a big design, but rather a smallish one.  It will likely grow as you further develop your application.
2. You will put information into your tables by collecting the various values from the user interface and preparing a series of INSERT statements to be sent to the database engine.  Each INSERT will add a row to a table.  If you are using database-generated IDs then you will probably have to retrieve them between INSERTs and use the value as part of the subsequent INSERT statement.
3. You'll get the data back using one or more SELECT statements that get data from a single table or JOIN data from several different tables.  If you find that these JOINed SELECT statements constitute important, often used concepts you may choose to encapsulate them in some VIEWs.

Comment: lol so it IS REALLY SMALL!

about the select, could you provide any example to any of your methods..or comparison between the methods I could use to achieve my data retrieval ?

Answer (score 3):

To try to answer your questions:

1. This is a pretty small design.  My current project at work has 150 tables, arranged not unlike what you have.
2. Ideally to enter a new kid you'll have to only enter data in the Kid table.  The easiest way to visualize this from a GUI point of view is to have one GUI table per database table.  That way you can specify the Parents, Sponsors, Skills, Fields of Work, etc., on their own forms.
3. You'll have to ask yourself how much information is appropriate to supply for each kid based on the need.  An interface that showed a list of kids with their parents, favorite toy, sponsors, skills, etc., will become way too crowded.  Depending on your application, you'll probably want to be more specific on what data you show.  For example, you might want to list all the information for kids when you specify them by name.  If you need to query for kids who are sponsored by plumbers (sponsors' fields of work), for example, you probably don't care what their favorite toy is.

Comment: point one (Y) Note taken....point 2 and 3 are noted as well, but although it doesn't seem to people that it's appropriate or optimum to select all this information at once, but after talking with the guy, his application is very complicated for his certain use...so in the end I really need to retrieve all those information at once about a certain or a set of kids!...Thanks for the advice though :) And I hope if you are already familliar with such cases to help me with some code!